# Unable to checked Bottom Navigation View item

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bottomnavigationview, onbackpressed

I have two Activities called 'MainActivity' and 'LibraryActivity'. These two activities are using the same 'Bottom Navigation View'. In this case I have managed to select the correct item (highlighted with a different color) when 
the intent calls the 'LibraryActivity'. The problem is coming back to the 'MainActivity' by using 'onBackPressed()' from 'LibraryActivity' bottom 'Navigation View' item is not highlighted with a different color.

Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

        context = this;

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

 // used to highlight the correct item

        Menu bottomMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i=0; i<bottomMenu.size(); i++)
        {
            MenuItem bottomMenuItem = bottomMenu.getItem(0);
            bottomMenuItem.setChecked(true);
        }

// item click listener

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_library:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LibraryActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("NUM", "0");
                                startActivity(intent);

                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }
```

**LibraryActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);

        context = this;

        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);

// used to highlight the correct item

        Menu bottomMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        for (int i=0; i<bottomMenu.size(); i++)
        {
            MenuItem bottomMenuItem = bottomMenu.getItem(1);
            bottomMenuItem.setChecked(true);
        }

// item click listener

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.action_for_you:
                                onBackPressed();

                                break;

                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: @Jantzilla: regarding your edit, bolding whole sentences rarely makes them more readable. In general, bold is not needed at all in a readable piece of writing, with the exception of headings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this code ,

```
   Menu bottomMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i=0; i<bottomMenu.size(); i++)
    {
        MenuItem bottomMenuItem = bottomMenu.getItem(0);
        bottomMenuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
```

and place it here ,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Menu bottomMenu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i=0; i<bottomMenu.size(); i++)
    {
        MenuItem bottomMenuItem = bottomMenu.getItem(0);
        bottomMenuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

So that it gets updated when it resumes after some other activity finishes and the current activity is resumed.